# How to see where the error is in the codes from Visual C++ 6.0 debugger?

Tags: visual-c++

[image: Visual C++ 6.0 Debugger]

Hi, how do I see where the error is in the codes from Visual C++ 6.0 debugger? Currently it shows "Unhandled exception in XYTable.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation" warning box and also some random numbers and alphabets as shown in the link above.

Comment: "random numbers and alphabets" - you mean the disassembly view? Try the call stack window if you can't read that, and hopefully there will be some lines in your code you can jump to and look at. (assuming this is a project you've compiled and run from the IDE, or otherwise have PDB information for)

Comment: That said, your example has the cursor on an "int 3" line which is a debug breakpoint, so looks wrong to me :-/